# Blocking in AG that causes app not to launch

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

If lag between primary and secondary is huge, then can it cause persistent blocking on app sessions? Coz recently we had an issue where blocking sessions were having wait type as HADR_SYNC_COMMIT and there was lag for one of the DB in AG.

So we failover to Secondary even though the lag was pretty high. After DB coming online on new Primary, issue got resolved.

But today the issue happened again. Can you please help.

Comment: Yes, that could cause commits to be very slow and result in locks being held much longer.  Without more information there's not much we can do to help.  In general you have to start looking for evidence of anything with the OS, hardware, network, VM host, and SQL Server that might be causing poor I/O or network performance.

Answer (score 0):

As addition to Tony's comment this [MSDN post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/troubleshooting-high-hadr_sync_commit-wait-type-with-always-on-availability-groups/) can help you with performance counters and latency factors.

Also, verify one of the known issue (lag) "redo blocking on secondary due to schema changes on primary", you can verify that via built-in Xevent's session or [follow these steps](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/247009/185080) for validation of redo blocking and quick fix.